# Machine understand natural language - nlp

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

What are the tools that are currently available for the machine to understand natural language
and algorithms available

Comment: @JerwinRoy please don't suggest edits like that.

Comment: @Second Rikudo okay fine

Comment: @JerwinRoy "machine" in this context is abstract, meaning "totally autonomous". It doesn't refer to a particular computer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check these out in that order :) [Natural Language Tool Kit [NLTK] main page](http://www.nltk.org)(It is in Python),[Building a machine learning class around NLTK](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/os-pythonnltk/index.html) And
[Making an actual Application out of it](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/carljv/Will_it_Python/blob/master/MLFH/CH3/ch3_nltk.ipynb).
This should give you a great foundation for building NLP applications(provided your NLP fundamentals are strong)